# DateTimeFormatInfo string format for day of week. Thursday becomes Th

Tags: c#, .net, datetimeformatinfo

Is there a `DateTimeFormatInfo` format pattern to convert a day of week to two characters? For example Tuesday becomes Tu, Wednesday becomes We. The format string needs to conform to the `DateTimeFormatInfo`  for date formats.

**Addition:**

Maybe I am looking for a solution to extend `DateTimeFormatInfo` to include custom formats?

Comment: Check out my post on AbbreviatedDayNames.

Answer (score 22):

The closes you can get is the `"ddd"` [custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) - this produces three lettered abbreviations, so not exactly what you want. There is nothing built in that does exactly what you want.

You can always take the first two characters of that:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd").Substring(0,2);
```

Unfortunately you can't extend [`DateTimeFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx) since it is declared as `sealed`.

Comment: I know but it's not two characters like I want.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich - So, you want to use a format pattern that does not exist in the framework?

Comment: Yes but if this will gets too complicated then "ddd" might do.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich - `DateTimeFormatInfo` cannot be extended, as it is declared as `sealed`.

Comment: @Steven - You are right. But that doesn't give you a two letter abbreviation as the OP asked for.

Answer (score 5):

You need to get the `DateTimeFormatInfo` of the culture you're working with, then modify the array of strings called `AbbreviatedDayNames`.  After that, `ddd` will return `Th` for you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.abbreviateddaynames(VS.71).aspx

> **DateTimeFormatInfo.AbbreviatedDayNames**
>   Gets or sets a one-dimensional array
>   of type String containing the
>   culture-specific abbreviated names of
>   the days of the week.

Here's a sample of how to do it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var dtInfo = new System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo();            
        Console.WriteLine("Old array of abbreviated dates:");
        var dt = DateTime.Today;
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dt.AddDays(i).ToString("ddd", dtInfo));
        }

        // change the short weekday names array
        var newWeekDays = 
            new string[] { "Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa" };
        dtInfo.AbbreviatedDayNames = newWeekDays;

        Console.WriteLine("New array of abbreviated dates:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dt.AddDays(i).ToString("ddd", dtInfo));
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

One more note:  of course, if you are constrained from providing the `IFormatProvider`, then you can override the current thread's `CultureInfo`, for example:

```
CultureInfo customCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
// ... set up the DateTimeFormatInfo, etc...

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;
```

More on CurrentCulture:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture.aspx

> **Thread.CurrentUICulture
>   Property**
>  Gets or sets the
>   current culture used by the Resource
>   Manager to look up culture-specific
>   resources at run time.

Comment: I forgot to mention this, but any time you create a new instance of DateTimeInfo, the instance is created from the invariant culture, so just keep this in mind.  Of course if you're going to completely customize the DateTimeInfo then this becomes a moot point.

Comment: dt.AddDays(i).ToString("ddd", dtInfo) is deprecated. dtInfo.GetDayName(dt.DayOfWeek) should work.

Comment: @Joshcodes: that'll get you "Thursday", not "Th". Remember, what I'm doing here is replacing the default abbreviated day names, then invoking them. What you are doing, is using the full unabbreviated day name.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
string s = DateVar.ToString("ddd").SubString(0,2);
```

If it needs to be a FormatPattern, then try this:

```
var dtFI = new CultureInfo( "en-US", false).DateTimeFormat;
dtFI.DayNames = new[] {"Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su" };
string s = DateVar.ToString("ddd", dtFI);
```

Answer (score 1):

To use the DateTimeFormatInfo specifically you can

```
dtfi.GetShortestDayName(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek);
```

however "ddd" is the closest you'll get for a string format